# Showing Volume on the Daily chart in Premarket

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to show cumulative premarket volume on the daily chart. I cannot get pine script to show anything on the daily chart during premarket. I am trying to debug my problem (and hence put in 100K as a default for now. I thought this should create a volume candle of 100K volume on the daily chart in the premarket. But nothing shows up.

```
plotVolume = timeInRange(timeframe.period, "0400-0930") ? 100000 : volume
plot(plotVolume, color = color.new(palette,15), style=plot.style_columns, title="Volume")
```

My thought process: Get the 100K volume candle to show up on the daily chart in the premarket...once that is successful, replace 100K with a cumulative volume function of the 5M chart using request.security. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

This will do it.
You must also enable extended hours on your chart.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Cumulative volume', 'CV')

var float   cv = 0

// Reset volume when a new day has started, or when market session begins
if (dayofmonth != dayofmonth[1]) or (session.ismarket and session.ispremarket[1])
    cv := 0

cv += volume

plot(cv, style=plot.style_columns)
```

**Edit 1** in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754079/showing-volume-on-the-daily-chart-in-premarket/70754325?noredirect=1#comment125088401_70754325)

For the previous solution, you must be on a lower timeframe than daily.
But I see now you want to keep your chart on the daily timeframe, AND see the pre-market volume.
To make that happen, you'll have to look inside the bar, to the lower timeframe (1 minute in my example below).
But I doubt it will work, because you need a bar on the daily timeframe to look inside of, and in the pre-market you don't have a bar yet. You can try though.
If it doesn't work, then I don't think it can be done in Pine afaik, unless someone else knows of a way to do this.

Should it work, also be aware that the data will not be the most accurate, because:
*`security()` on lower intervals doesn’t always return reliable data. Intrabar volume information on stocks, for example, will not match >1D volume, as data for both is reported differently by exchanges.*

For more information about intrabar inspection, you can take a look at [Is it possible to use security() on lower intervals than the chart’s current interval?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#is-it-possible-to-use-security-on-lower-intervals-than-the-charts-current-interval)

```
//@version=5
indicator('IntraBar Volume')

f_intrabar(_src, _res) =>
    var int _barNo = 0
    var float _value = na
    
    if ta.change(time(_res))
        _value := 0

    _value += _src
    
intraBarVolume = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1', f_intrabar(volume, 'D'))
    
plot(intraBarVolume, style=plot.style_columns)
```

Comment: thanks I will check this tomorrow morning during PM...I am actually using request.security to get the volume for a smaller timeframe and adding it on the daily PM chart, because I thought volume will return nothing for a daily chart in the PM. I will check it tomorrow morning and let you know. thanks again!

Comment: Added Edit 1 section.

Comment: you were right about the accuracy (or lackof) and using security on lower intervals. i give up :) thanks for your help!
One main hinderance was not being able to distinguish between PM and regular session on the daily chart.

Comment: You can distinguish between PM and RTH, but only on an intraday chart. Not on daily and above. Try this on an intraday chart, with extended hours enabled `bgcolor(session.ispremarket ? color.red : color.green)`